# List all disks except DVD drive without using DriveInfo.GetDrives

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I list all disks except DVD drives **without using DriveInfo.GetDrives**? I'm using the Unity game engine and it throws an error on GetDrives:

> NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.
>   System.IO.DriveInfo.WindowsGetDrives

I'm looking for a workaround. I've read that Winbase.h has a DriveType enum, is there any way I could use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't, not without sacrificing platform-independence.**

The following will get *all* drives.  I don't think there's a platform-independent way of getting "all drives except DVD":

```
string[] drives = Directory.GetLogicalDrives();
```

You mentioned Winbase.h.  That's C++, and will tie you to a particular platform (Windows).  You *can* do this, using p/invoke, but you will have to write platform-dependent code.  I wouldn't recommend P/invoke for beginners.  It's an advanced topic that can get difficult pretty quickly.

What does "platform-dependent" mean?  You would have to write code for Windows, code for Linux, code for Mac, and any other platforms your code will run on.  One of Unity's selling points is you can write code *once* and expect it to run the same on a variety of different platforms.

Comment: Thanks. I found this post https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/257251-how-detect-hard-drives before posting here but didn't know what namespace to use, your tip about p/invoke helped me figure it out. I'll also post an answer for other Unity users in case the link goes dead.

Comment: I'm glad to hear my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Amy's answer I found [this post](https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/257251-how-detect-hard-drives) by C.R. Timmons Consulting, Inc. Tested and working on Windows, I'd be grateful if someone on Mac could check if it works too:

```
public enum DriveType : int
{
Unknown = 0,
NoRoot = 1,
Removable = 2,
Localdisk = 3,
Network = 4,
CD = 5,
RAMDrive = 6
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int GetDriveType(string lpRootPathName);
```

Example usage:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

void GetDrives()
{
     foreach (string s in Environment.GetLogicalDrives())
     Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Drive {0} is a {1}.",
     s, Enum.GetName(typeof(DriveType), GetDriveType(s))));
}
```

Comment: Nope, that DllImport won't work on a Mac (DLLs in general are specific to windows).  It will require completely different code that flows along the same lines (a second DllImport just like the first, but slightly different to work on a Mac).  The way this is normally handled is through the `#if` and `#endif` compiler directives, which would activate/deactivate your code depending on compiler flags.

Comment: Note also that using p/invoke requires that your software run in "full trust" mode.  This *probably* won't be a problem, but I bring it up just as a heads up.